# How to correctly rewrite url from one to another without affecting other files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have single page application with couple of URLs, It's Apache.

```
/
/about
/contact
```

etc, very simple

```
/
```

will get index.html where my app is, I would like /about to also request index.html so I could resolve the URL inside my single page application.

I tried to add this to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   about   index.html
```

It seems to work but **it also redirected my module-about.js file to index.html** which is not very nice. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this above your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

The first one will make it skip existing files, and the second will make it skip existing directories.

Comment: Hey do I have to put it before every rule or is there a way to make it work for multiple rules? This seems counter productive: rewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   about   index.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   offer   index.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   quality   index.html (...)

Comment: Unfortunately, you'd need to specify the condition for each rule. Per [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond): "One or more RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive. The following rule is then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its pattern, and if these conditions are met." However, instead of using one rule for each page, you should use a *wildcard* rule to match all the pages. This could work for you: `RewriteRule [a-z0-9-]+ index.html [NC,L]`.